# Cloud Functions for Firebase onCreate() dates not formatted correctly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export default functions.auth.user().onCreate(saveUserToDatabase);

async function saveUserToDatabase(event) {
    const Users = admin.database().ref('Users');
    const authUser = event.data;

    let user = await Users.child(authUser.uid).set({
        createdAt: authUser.metadata.createdAt.toString(),
        email: authUser.email,
        facebookId: authUser.providerData[0].uid.replace('http://facebook.com/', ''),
        lastSignedInAt: authUser.metadata.lastSignedInAt.toString(),
        name: authUser.displayName,
        photoUrl: authUser.photoURL,
    });

    console.log('saveUserToDatabase()');
    console.log(authUser);
}
```

In the above code I save a user to the firebase database when they register. Now unless I use the `toString` method on the dates they do not save. I looked into this a little further and found that the dates don't come in as strings and that is causing some issues. (I did this with console.log and checking the firebase dashboard)

```
{ displayName: 'Test User',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  metadata: 
   { createdAt: 2017-05-02T05:18:45.000Z,
     lastSignedInAt: 2017-05-02T05:18:45.000Z }
}
```

When I use the toString method though it converts the output to:

```
"Tue May 02 2017 05:24:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
```

Dates are also saved in some instances in this format:

```
"1492213242000"
```

1. Why is there so many timestamp formats?
2. What is the preferred timestamp format for firebase I should be using?
3. How do I convert the dates into the preferred timestamp using cloud functions?

Comment: Your life will be greatly simplified if you just use "epoch time" representation, which is the number of seconds (or milliseconds) since Jan 1, 1970.  Anything else will cause you problem unless you have a special need.

Answer (score 0):

The object you're receiving in `event.data` is an [`admin.auth.UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord). Its interface specifies that the `createdAt` and `lastSignedInAt` timestamps should be JavaScript `Date` objects.

The `Date` type has enough [issues](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/) that we try to avoid it in newer interfaces. I suspect you may be hitting some of those pain points in the inconsistent `toString()` serialization.

I agree with Doug that for storage, milliseconds since the epoch should be the preferred format. You should be able to get that from `createdAt.value`, for example.